# How to reorder the articles in Joomla backend?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4

How can I reorder the Joomla articles in back end or (how can I change the ID number). Suppose there is an article with id number 10, I want to change this id to 9. How can I do that?

In menu items we are able to drag the items up and down. is there a such facility available for articles?

Thank you.

Comment: In the Article Manager, the Ordering column no longer works - no arrows, no numbers, no drag-n-drop icons. This is also the same for Featured Articles. However, Categories works fine.

Comment: Did you sort your table by the column "Ordering" by clicking on the column header or via the drop down in the top right corner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use drag-and-drop ordering you must sort by the order column. Click the up/down caret column heading to do so.